# IEnumerator method to calculate next result in background for quicker response

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, ienumerable, ienumerator, yield-return

I have a method that returns `IEnumerator` and it has a long calculation process on each record. How can I make it not fully stuck on its `yield return` command but work on next record calculation in background for quicker next response? I do not care much about thread safety much because the consumer of this method is in a different class, and these two classes are pretty isolated to each other.

```
private int[] numbers = new int[] { 45, 43, 76, 23, 54, 22 };

private static int GetFibonacci(int n)
{
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) return n;
    else return GetFibonacci(n - 1) + GetFibonacci(n - 2);
}

public IEnumerator<int> GetFibonaccies()
{
    foreach (int n in numbers)
    {
        int f = GetFibonacci(n); // long job
        yield return f; // << please do not be lazy and do not stuck
                        // here till next request, but calculate next
                        // number in background to quickly respond
                        // your next request
    }
}
```

Comment: The `yield return` command yields control to the caller, so it can only get stuck if the caller enumerates lazily the produced enumerator. Is this the scenario upon which you are trying to improve? In other words do you want to calculate the next Fibonacci number while the caller is sleeping (or working with other things) between consecutive `Enumerator.MoveNext()` invocations? Or you want to speed things up even if the caller enumerates the enumerator non-stop, without imposing any delay in the enumeration?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias right, Theodor, while the caller is doing his job on a received object, the IEnumerator method should already be working on calculation of its next result object.

Comment: Somewhat related: [How to enumerate an IAsyncEnumerable<T> and invoke an async action for each element, allowing concurrency for each iteration/action pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66192350/how-to-enumerate-an-iasyncenumerablet-and-invoke-an-async-action-for-each-elem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an extension method `WithPreloadNext` for `IEnumerable<T>`s, that offloads the next [`MoveNext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext) invocation to the `ThreadPool` while the previous value is yielded to the caller:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WithPreloadNext<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    // Argument validation omitted
    using var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    Task<(bool, T)> task = Task.Run(() => enumerator.MoveNext() ?
        (true, enumerator.Current) : (false, default));
    while (true)
    {
        var (moved, value) = task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        if (!moved) break;
        task = Task.Run(() => enumerator.MoveNext() ?
            (true, enumerator.Current) : (false, default));
        yield return value;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
private IEnumerable<int> GetFibonacciesInternal()
{
    foreach (int n in numbers) yield return GetFibonacci(n);
}

public IEnumerable<int> GetFibonaccies() => GetFibonacciesInternal().WithPreloadNext();
```

**Note:** Offloading the `MoveNext` means that the source enumerable is not enumerated on the context of the caller. So this method should not be used in case the source enumerable has thread affinity to the current thread. For example in case of a Windows Forms application where the enumerable interacts with UI components.

Comment: Ran a quick test of this approach in asp.net Core. What would be the correct test-setup for proving that this approach is working? Iterating is somewhat slower when using WithPreloadNext. BR

Comment: @Roar yeap, the `Task.Run` has some overhead, and if the caller enumerates the enumerable in full speed the overhead will show up. The `WithPreloadNext` is only beneficial if the caller has to do additional work while enumerating the enumerable. For example `foreach (var n in GetFibonaccies()) { Console.WriteLine(n); Thread.Sleep(100); }`

Answer (score 1):

I used the code below to run a test for this case. The idea in `FibonacciTestAsync` is to run multiple computations in parallel.

Answer is divided into a C# 7 and a C# 8 part.

**Answer when using C# 7**

*Test durations with sequence 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45*:

- FibonacciTestAsync: ~31 seconds
- FibonacciTestNonAsync: ~76 seconds

Please note that these results are significantly slower than results from the asp.net Core-section below.

Environment: Windows 10, VS 2017, .NET Framework 4.6.1, NUnit, Resharper

```
private static readonly int[] Numbers = { 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45 };

private static int GetFibonacci(int n)
{
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) return n;
    return GetFibonacci(n - 1) + GetFibonacci(n - 2);
}

private static Task<int> GetFibonacciAsync(int n) => Task.Run(() => GetFibonacci(n));

public static IEnumerator<int> GetFibonaccies()
{
    foreach (var n in Numbers)
    {
        var f = GetFibonacci(n); // long job
        yield return f; // << please do not be lazy and do not stuck here till next request but calculate next number in background to quickly respond your next request
    }
}

// in C# 8: public static async IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetFibonacciesAsync()
public static IEnumerable<int> GetFibonacciesAsync()
{
    var taskList = Numbers
        .Select(GetFibonacciAsync)
        .ToList();

    foreach (var task in taskList)
    {
        // in C# 8: yield return await task;
        yield return task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}

private static readonly IList<int> ExpectedOutput = new List<int>
{
    102334155,
    165580141,
    267914296,
    433494437,
    701408733,
    1134903170
};

[Test]
public void FibonacciTestNonAsync()
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    var result = new List<int>();

    using (var fibonacciNumberEnumerator = GetFibonaccies())
    {
        while (fibonacciNumberEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            result.Add(fibonacciNumberEnumerator.Current);
            Console.WriteLine(fibonacciNumberEnumerator.Current);
        }
    }

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed={0}", (double)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000);

    Assert.AreEqual(ExpectedOutput, result);
}

[Test]
public void FibonacciTestAsync()
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    var result = new List<int>();

    // here you can play a little bit:
    // Try to replace GetFibonacciesAsync() with GetFibonacciesAsync().Take(1) and observe that the test will run a lot faster
    var fibonacciNumbers = GetFibonacciesAsync();
    foreach (var item in fibonacciNumbers)
    {
        result.Add(item);
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed={0}", (double)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000);

    Assert.AreEqual(ExpectedOutput, result);
}
```

---

**Answer when using C# 8 or higher**

*Test durations with sequence 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45*:

- FibonacciTestAsync: ~11 seconds
- FibonacciTestNonAsync: ~26 seconds

Environment used during testing: Windows 10, VS 2019, asp.net Core 5, NUnit, Resharper

```
// original array from OP, takes too long too compute private static readonly int[] Numbers = { 45, 43, 76, 23, 54, 22 };

private static readonly int[] Numbers = { 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45 };

private static int GetFibonacci(int n)
{
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) return n;
    return GetFibonacci(n - 1) + GetFibonacci(n - 2);
}

private static Task<int> GetFibonacciAsync(int n) => Task.Run(() => GetFibonacci(n));

public static IEnumerator<int> GetFibonaccies()
{
    foreach (int n in Numbers)
    {
        var f = GetFibonacci(n); // long job
        yield return f; // << please do not be lazy and do not stuck here till next request but calculate next number in background to quickly respond your next request
    }
}

public static async IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetFibonacciesAsync()
{
    var taskList = Numbers
        .Select(GetFibonacciAsync) // starting task here
        .ToList();

    foreach (var task in taskList)
    {
        yield return await task; // as soon as current task is completed, yield the result
    }
}

private static readonly IList<int> ExpectedOutput = new List<int>
{
    102334155,
    165580141,
    267914296,
    433494437,
    701408733,
    1134903170
};

[Test]
public void FibonacciTestNonAsync()
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    var result = new List<int>();

    using IEnumerator<int> fibonacciNumberEnumerator = GetFibonaccies();
    while (fibonacciNumberEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        result.Add(fibonacciNumberEnumerator.Current);
        Console.WriteLine(fibonacciNumberEnumerator.Current);
    }

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed={0}", (double)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000);

    Assert.AreEqual(ExpectedOutput, result);
}

[Test]
public async Task FibonacciTestAsync()
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    var result = new List<int>();

    var fibonacciNumbers = GetFibonacciesAsync();
    await foreach (var item in fibonacciNumbers)
    {
        result.Add(item);
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed={0}", (double)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000);

    Assert.AreEqual(ExpectedOutput, result);
}
```

Comment: I see that new C#8 feature IAsyncEnumerable does the trick in your solution. I should have mentioned that I use .NET Framework 4.7.2 for a reason. If nobody gives another solution in 3 days, I will mark your answer as accepted. I had an idea to make the method put its results to a collection, and the caller to get data from that collection, but my experience is far from enough to implement that idea. And I do not know how to signal the caller that the result list has ended to add anything new to the collection.

Comment: @meir: Added a C# 7 solution to my answer. It is indeed interesting to see the difference in speed between asp.net Core and .NET Framework. BR

Comment: @meir: To the remaining part of your last comment: Maybe you are looking for a different approach. I don't know your case in details, but you may want to have a look at a delegate approach I added to the end of my answer. BR

Comment: The `await Task.Delay(1);` trick is not a reliable way to offload the code that follows to the `ThreadPool`. There are at least two problems with this approach. The correct way to do it is with `Task.Run`: `static Task<int> GetFibonacciAsync(int n) => Task.Run(() => GetFibonacci(n));`

Comment: Also my understanding is that the OP does not want to parallelize the `GetFibonacci` invocations. They only want to parallelize the next `GetFibonacci` invocation with the code that consumes the previous value.