# XDocument to DataTable async

Tags: c#, xml, async-await, parallel-processing

I am loading data from 100-500 XML files into a `DataTable` to populate an Infragistics UltraGrid. The files are as small as 100K and as large as 2MB. I've been looking into ways to speed up the load times and considered async, but datatables aren't thread safe.

Looking at the process, loading the xdoc takes about 2/3 of the time, the other 1/3 is in reading the xdoc and adding data to the table.

Is there a way to use async and somehow load the next `XDocument` while the previous one is read and loaded into the datatable? I've looked but I'm not seeing a good way to do this in a for each. Are there some other strategies I should consider?

Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
private void openXMLs(){
    
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog
    {
        Title = "Browse XML files",
        CheckFileExists = true,
        CheckPathExists = true,
        DefaultExt = "xml",
        Filter = @"XML files (*.xml)|*.xml",
        FilterIndex = 2,
        RestoreDirectory = true,
        ReadOnlyChecked = true,
        ShowReadOnly = true,
        Multiselect = true
    };

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
        {
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(file)
            loadData(xdoc)
        }
    }
}
        
private void loadData(XDocument xdoc){
        
    var query = xdoc.Descendants("root").AsEnumerable()
    .Select(c => new
    {
        id = c.Element("ID").Value,
        firstname = c.Element("firstname").Value,
        lastname = c.Element("lastname").Value,
        state = c.Element("state").Value,

    });
    
    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        _dt.Rows.Add(
            item.id,
            item.firstname,
            item.lastname,
            item.state
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Somewhat related: [How to enumerate an IAsyncEnumerable<T> and invoke an async action for each element, allowing concurrency for each iteration/action pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66192350/how-to-enumerate-an-iasyncenumerablet-and-invoke-an-async-action-for-each-elem)

Comment: *I am loading data from 100-500 XML files into a DataTable* << why? I mean seriously why do you need to overstuff a table with hundreds of datasets?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the environment I have to work in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, however, there is no single answer to this question. You could do it in several ways, here is one:

```
private async Task openXMLs() {
    
    // .. dialog ..

    var loadTasks = new List<Task>();        
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
        {
            var xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(file);
            XDocument xdoc = await XDocument.LoadAsync(xmlFile, LoadOptions.None, CancellationToken.None);
            loadTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => loadData(xdoc));
        }
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(loadTasks);
}
```

However, the datatable is not thread safe and you will need to lock access to it. This also does not guarantee order in which documents will be added.

```
private void loadData(XDocument xdoc){
    
    var query = xdoc.Descendants("root").AsEnumerable()
    .Select(c => new
    {
        id = c.Element("ID").Value,
        firstname = c.Element("firstname").Value,
        lastname = c.Element("lastname").Value,
        state = c.Element("state").Value,

    });
    
    lock(_dt) {
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            _dt.Rows.Add(
                item.id,
                item.firstname,
                item.lastname,
                item.state
             );
        }
    }
}
```

This will load current document while next one reads from the disk.

Comment: Thanks for this, I couldn't quite wrap my head around how to do it, but seeing this now it makes perfect sense. I did an initial test and it looks like this is going to make my load times about twice as fast, so this is just what I needed. One note, I could not do await XDocument.LoadAsync. Am I missing something? Will I have issues leaving it as XDocument.Load?

Comment: Unfortunately, the `LoadAsync` does not seem to have overload to accept file parameter, but I think you can use `XmlReader`. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could parallelize the loading of the next `XDocument` from the filesystem, while the previous document is loaded to the `DataTable`, by using the `ParallelForEachPairwise` extension method that is shown below:

```
/// <summary>
/// Invokes two consecutive actions on each element in the source sequence.
/// The first action is invoked in parallel with the second action for the
/// previous element, and with fetching the sequence's next element.
/// </summary>
public static void ParallelForEachPairwise<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TResult> offloadedAction,
    Action<TResult> synchronousAction)
{
    using var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) return;
    Task<TResult> task = Offload(enumerator.Current);
    try
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            TResult result = task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            task = Offload(enumerator.Current);
            synchronousAction(result);
        }
        synchronousAction(task.GetAwaiter().GetResult());
    }
    finally { task.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); } // Prevent fire-and-forget

    Task<TResult> Offload(TSource item) => Task.Run(() => offloadedAction(item));
}
```

The `ParallelForEachPairwise` takes two delegates as arguments. The first delegate (`offloadedAction`) is offloaded to the `ThreadPool`, by the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method. The second delegate (`synchronousAction`) is invoked synchronously on the current thread. These delegates are invoked in parallel to each other, but repeated invocations of each individual delegate are sequential. So you don't have to worry about thread-safety, provided that each delegate does not produce side-effects that are visible from the other delegate.

Usage example:

```
openFileDialog1.FileNames.ParallelForEachPairwise(file =>
{
    return XDocument.Load(file);
}, xdoc =>
{
    loadData(xdoc);
});
```

...or more succinctly:

```
openFileDialog1.FileNames.ParallelForEachPairwise(XDocument.Load, loadData);
```

Comment: This looks like an interesting approach, I'll try and test it as well to see how it stacks up against the other. Thanks!

Comment: @Fisher8370 this is a conservative approach to parallelism. You can expect at maximum a 2x performance boost with it, but it comes almost for free. The storage driver and the CPU will not be taxed with considerable extra work, compared to the simple sequential approach.